# GDAL - creating tiles from TIFF with world file

Tags: gdal, tiles, gdal2tiles

Several years ago I created multiple tiles (xyz) from orthophotomaps using GDAL with success but now I'm getting this error and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "gdal2tiles.py", line 2903, in <module>
main()
File "gdal2tiles.py", line 2897, in main
single_threaded_tiling(input_file, output_folder, options)
File "gdal2tiles.py", line 2831, in single_threaded_tiling
conf, tile_details = worker_tile_details(input_file, output_folder, options)
File "gdal2tiles.py", line 2751, in worker_tile_details
gdal2tiles.open_input()
File "gdal2tiles.py", line 1468, in open_input
in_srs, self.in_srs_wkt = setup_input_srs(input_dataset, self.options)
File "gdal2tiles.py", line 705, in setup_input_srs
input_srs.SetAxisMappingStrategy(osr.OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo/osr.py", line 297, in <lambda>
__getattr__ = lambda self, name: _swig_getattr(self, SpatialReference, name)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo/osr.py", line 80, in _swig_getattr
raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (class_type.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'SpatialReference' object has no attribute 'SetAxisMappingStrategy'
```

I have approx 100 TIFF files with world file for each one. I tried to do the following:

Create VRT file from TIFF files:

```
gdalbuildvrt -addalpha -a_srs EPSG:5514 tiles.vrt *.tif
```

Use GDAL warp:

```
gdalwarp -srcnodata 255,255,255 -dstnodata 0,0,0 -t_srs EPSG:5514 tiles.vrt output.tif
```

Create tiles:

```
gdal2tiles -s EPSG:5514 -z 15-16 output.tif tile_folder/
```

I tried different commands with different settings but still the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you install a bit older GDAL 2.x version and have a try with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user30184 I installed GDAL 2.4.2 instead of 3.x and now the command gdal2tiles run without error.